# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>' with an argument list of type '(Int32?)'

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to implement some methods and pointers of ffmpeg to Swift but converting it to Swift is a little complex. What does this error mean?

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafeMutablePointer' with an argument list of type '(Int32?)'?

Code is below

```
let pictureFrameData = av_malloc(Int(numBytes))
                                var test = frame?.pointee.linesize.0.
                                av_image_fill_arrays(UnsafeMutablePointer(frameRGB?.pointee.data.0),
                                                     UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>(frame?.pointee.linesize.0)!,
                                                     pictureFrameData,
                                                     frameRGB?.pointee.format,
                                                     frameRGB?.pointee.width,
                                                     frameRGB?.pointee.height,
                                                     1)
```

the error is at this line `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>(frame?.pointee.linesize.0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function expects an `'UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>` argument
then you'll have to pass an `Int32` value as “inout parameter” with `&`:

```
var linesize: Int32 = ...
av_image_fill_arrays(..., &lineSize, ...)
```